# dudas sobre JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Hola Buenas recién estoy empezando en esto y tengo una duda ,estoy haciendo un programa que tiene varias ventana, pero me estaba dando problemas y ahora pase a usar solo 1 pantalla ,que la voy adaptando a las medidas, me gustaría saber si al hacer todo en 1 solo JFrame me puede molestar algo en el codigo,me refiero si puede usar mas memoria o ande mas lento.Gracias y espero su respuesta ;)

Comment: Desde que el código este bien estructurado no debería fallar, ya si la app va a crecer mucho, ya creería que lo mejor para el rendimiento es que separes los componentes

Comment: buenas Daniel muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me podías explicar a que te referís cuando decís "que separes los componentes" , te referís a crearlo en otra class?

Comment: En otros jframes

Comment: Una pregunta disculpen mi ignorancia en todo esto , pero si yo agrego mas JFrame eso no me puede afectar al codigo? En el sentido volverlo mas lento ?

Comment: Claro que no, tendrías que tener bucles infinitos sin control para que algo así pasará, pero no esta mal que te pongas en la tarea de investigar mas sobre como funcionan las clases, los métodos y todo lo que estes usando en `JAVA`

Comment: Muchas Gracias Daniel, de apoco voy aprendiendo de todo esto